# How to show that the diffusion of a species is given by $\frac{\dot{m}}{A}=-\rho_i D \ln(C_i)$?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, density, diffusion, transport-phenomena

I'm reading a textbook on viscous flow which says that you can go from Fick's Law for the diffusion of a species

$$\dot{m_i}/A = -D \nabla \rho_i$$

to an equivalent formulation using the species concentration $C_i=\rho_i/\rho$.

$$\frac{\dot{m}}{A}=-\rho_i D \ln(C_i)$$

I tried to derive this but I'm running into trouble.

Substitute $\rho_i = C_i \rho$ into Fick's Law and apply the product rule for differentiation to $C_i \rho$:

$$\dot{m}/A = -D (\rho \nabla C_i + C_i \nabla \rho)$$

Then, use $\nabla C_i=C_i\nabla \ln C_i$

$$\dot{m}/A = -D (\rho_i\nabla \ln C_i + C_i \nabla \rho)$$

If it's possible to say that $C_i\nabla \rho\approx 0$, then we're done. But I'm struggling to understand how $\nabla \rho \approx 0$ if we are assuming that mass diffusion is occurring. That sort of assumes the existence of an overall density gradient, no?

Comment: Mass diffusion occurs even if the densities of the solute and solvent are equal. But in any case, if the species is dilute, the total density $\rho$ is nearly constant. Perhaps the derivation is implicitly applying that assumption.

Comment: I'd be happy to accept that as an answer.